# Function to generate random password in PLSQL

Tags: function, random, plsql, passwords

Function to create random password
Genpass(p integer,
p uppercase
p lowercase
p special characters)
return password varchar2;
select Genpassword(2,2,1,2)
It contain 2 numbers,2 uppercase characters ,special character like # and 2 numbers;

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is about random password generate function which creates passwords contain numbers ,letters and special characters in plsql

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you need a function? Do you have a function that is not working? What is your effort so far and where do you stuck?

Comment: create or replace FUNCTION GENPWD(
PNOIT IN NUMBER,
PSC IN NUMBER,
PL IN NUMBER,
PU IN NUMBER)
return varchar2 is

      pwd varchar2(11);

  begin
  select into
pwd:= dbms_random.string('U',pu),
pwd:=dbms_random.string('l',pl),
 pwd:= dbms_random.string('x',psc),
pwd:= dbms_random.string('a',pnoit)
from dual;
       return pwd;
        end;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle DBMS_RANDOM.STRING functionality does not allow you to state you want special characters expressly. Also, when you use DBMS_RANDOM.STRING for each type of character, you end up with a series that always has the same structure (which might even be a security issue again).

But if you do not want to have the same structure all the time, you would have to write something that would (in yet another random way) distribute the characters of your structured password.

Another option is to use an example I adopted from an AskTom entry; you leverage the existing functionality and try until you have a result:

```
create or replace FUNCTION GENPWD( 
  p_numbers      IN NUMBER, 
  p_specialchar  IN NUMBER, 
  p_lowercase    IN NUMBER, 
  p_uppercase    IN NUMBER) return varchar2 
IS
  v_length         number := p_numbers + p_specialchar + p_lowercase + p_uppercase;
  v_password       varchar2(200);
  v_iterations     number := 0;
  v_max_iterations number := 500;
BEGIN
    loop
        v_password := dbms_random.string('p',v_length);
        v_iterations := v_iterations + 1;

           exit when (regexp_count(v_password,'[a-z]') = p_lowercase
                 and  regexp_count(v_password,'[A-Z]') = p_uppercase
                 and  regexp_count(v_password,'[0-9]') = p_numbers) 
                 or v_iterations=v_max_iterations;

    end loop;

    if v_iterations = v_max_iterations THEN
      v_password := '';
    end if;

    return(v_password);
END;
```

Comment: can you convert this code in MYSQL

Comment: No sorry, I do not speak MySQL. I am only a SQL/PLSQL person